# vuejs2.0 webpack boilerplate: create sourcemap for css

Tags: css, webpack, vuejs2, source-maps, boilerplate

I try to create a sourceMap for my minified css. I use the  [vuew-webpack-boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)

In [build/utilys.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/build/utils.js) i added this to my loaders.

```
return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', {
        sourceMap: true
    }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass', {
        sourceMap: true
    }),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
  }
}
```

But "npm run build" doesn't create a sourcemap. Only the minified css file. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Enable sourcemaps in webpack is an option, more here: https://survivejs.com/webpack/building/source-maps/

Comment: @NathanielFlick I tried it this way beacause generateLoaders() has also a parameter for options  "function generateLoaders (loader, loaderOptions) {". Where should i place the code from webpack.config.js? Because in the vue webpack boilerplate i have no "webpack.config.js" file.

Comment: I imagine you will need a default config file, then add the sourcemap code to it: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html

Comment: i found a config folder with an index.js file https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/config/index.js and there is this line "productionSourceMap: true," inside the "build" property, so it should create an sourcemap... but it doesn't...

Comment: Looks like unless you have your local set for "production" not recommended, then it won't run.

Comment: Basic set up here, run it then add things to it when successful. http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#config-file

Comment: First thank you for your effort, but I'm sry if you have taken a look a the vuejs2.0 webpack boilerplate, you would have seen that inside the "package.json" no "webpack.config.js" is defined to run a build. The config file is splitted in many files (inside the config and build folder). If i run "npm run build"  this file will be called-> "build/build.js". My question was how i have to configure this boilerplate that i get a sourcemap for my css file and i don't want to write my own webpack.config.js file and change the whole boilerplate.